# Issue while running browserify on a simple angular app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, browserify

I'm making this very preliminary attempt of using node/npm/browserify to build my angular app. The ./app/controllers, ./app/directives, ./app/services basically have index.js files which in turn require() the js files! Below is the root js file i.e. public/index.js.

```
require('./app/controllers/');
require('./app/directives/');
require('./app/services/');

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/movie/:movieId", {
        template: require('./views/movie.html'),
        controller: 'MovieCtrl as movie'
    })
    .when("/movie/:movieId/scene/:sceneId", {
        template: require('./views/scene.html'),
        controller: 'SceneCtrl as scene'
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Now after running below command i do get a bundle.js however,

> browserify public/index.js -o release/bundle.js

However, the below line in bundle.js throws the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined"

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($route, $routeParams, $location, MyFactory) {
```

Now, i was assuming because var app is specified in index.js it should be accessible in MainCtrl.js. Could someone suggest how i could make this work?

----- Adding some more info ------
app/controllers/index.js contains below code:-

```
require('./MainCtrl.js')
require('./MovieCtrl.js')
require('./SceneCtrl.js')
```

And MainCtrl.js contains below code:-

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($route, $routeParams, $location, MyFactory) {
    //...
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where the line in your code is... it isn't clear from the question, but anyway:

> Now, i was assuming because var app is specified in index.js it should be accessible in MainCtrl.js.

That assumption is false.  You will need to pass in a reference to whatever you need when you instantiate whatever you included.

For example..

```
var mainCtrl = new MainCtrl(app);
```

Comment: hi Brad, added some code to hopefully make things more clear. Basically registering a controller on the main app called 'MainCtrl'.

Comment: Please ignore above ^ comment. I kind of figured out what was wrong. Posted answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i kind of understood what was going on. var app is local and cannot be accessible anywhere else. Once i set app to the global scope (which is obviously a horrible thing!) and required files after declaring app, it worked. This is mostly not the correct way of doing it, but as i mentioned this was a very preliminary attempt.

```
app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/movie/:movieId", {
        template: require('./views/movie.html'),
        controller: 'MovieCtrl as movie'
    })
    .when("/movie/:movieId/scene/:sceneId", {
        template: require('./views/scene.html'),
        controller: 'SceneCtrl as scene'
    });
});

require('./app/controllers/');
require('./app/directives/');
require('./app/services/');
```

Comment: Did you see my answer?  It gives you an alternative.  At least if you're going to make something global, put it in globals.